# How to use Wildcards on node attributes in cypher queries in neo4j

Tags: wildcard, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I'm trying to create a search from query parameters in Neo4j, but seem to have trouble identifying the wildcard.  "*" isn't working for wildcards on node attributes.

The code I have is below:

```
price = "*" # by default
query = 'start b = product("*:*") WHERE has(b.public) and (b.public = 1) and (b.price = %d) RETURN ID(b) SKIP %d LIMIT %d;' % (price, skip, limit)
cypher.execute(cdb,query)[0]
```

Unfortunately, when I run the query or switch to the console...

```
start b = product("*:*") WHERE has(b.public) and (b.public = 1) and (b.price = "*") RETURN ID(b) SKIP 0 LIMIT 10;
```

...I get null values as if price were trying to literally match "*" rather than match anything, as wildcard character would.  When I substitute the variable `price` with 0, for example, everything is fine.

I don't quite understand because [this](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-query-lang.html) suggests I can say things like:

```
WHERE follower.name =~ 'S.*'
```

and the "*" works as the wildcard for both count(*) and node:indexes("*:*")

I'm using python and py2neo if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-aggregation.html), the meaning of `count(*)` is to count the number of matching rows.  But remember, with matching we mean rows returned by the `MATCH` clause, and not a wildcard match. so the `"*"` is not an ordinary wildcard here.

And in `node:indexes("*:*")` the first "*" means "all keys" (of the index).  You cannot say `"i*"` in the meaning "all keys starting with the letter 'i'".

The second "*" means ALL indexed values.  But here, you can also say `"foo*"`, meaning "all values starting with 'foo'".

Finally, `"WHERE follower.name =~ 'S.*'"` is a **regexp** match.

For your case to work, there should exist a key named `"price"` on the product index.  Then you could use `"price:whatever"`.

Comment: Hmm. I still don't understand. That's a very clear explanation of how the different "*"s are not wildcards, and that's very helpful. But how can I sometimes pass in a value that is given, and sometimes pass in a value that counts for all?  You're suggesting a query like `start b = product("name:*", "price:%d") WHERE has(b.public) and (b.public = 1) RETURN ID(b) SKIP %d LIMIT %d; % (price, skip, limit)`?

Comment: If you, for some reason, want to do wildcard search on the price attribute, then this is the fastest solution.

Comment: OK, thanks.  That's not too strange a reason, right?  I'm going to pass GET arguments in from a search field.  If there are no arguments, I want to index return everything.